# 'Confirm' a user click

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I saw that when you press the button on the Television remote it doesn't go to the channel immediately, after some time it lands on the channel, but if you press the button within a certain time period it doesn't land.

Is there a way to do this in tkInter, where if the user clicks the button within a time period (in this case two seconds), the function doesn't get executed unless the user does not click the button.

To clarify, I want to delay command execution by 2 seconds so you can cancel it again if the user presses the same button again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always disconnect buttons and actions, and put a timer in-between that can be cancelled. Tkinter offers the [`Widget.after()` method](http://sandbox.effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to invoke a callback with a delay. You can also use a thread for this to give you more control.

The following implementation can be used as callback for any tkInter element; it takes a a delay (in seconds as a float) and callback to call once the delay has passed without another click. Two further optional callbacks are called immediately when the `DelayedCancellable()` is called, and when cancelled:

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

class DelayedCancellable:
    def __init__(self, delay, after_delay, invoked=None, cancelled=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._after_delay = after_delay
        self._on_invoked = invoked
        self._on_cancelled = cancelled
        self._delay = delay
        self._thread = None
        self._cancelled = Event()

    def __call__(self):
        if self._thread is not None and self._thread.is_alive():
            self._cancelled.set()
        else:
            if self._on_invoked is not None:
                self._on_invoked()
            self._thread = Thread(target=self._delayed_execution)
            self._thread.start()

    def _delayed_execution(self):
        try:
            if self._cancelled.wait(self._delay):
                # we got cancelled, exit
                if self._on_cancelled is not None:
                    self._on_cancelled()
                return
            self._after_delay()
        finally:
            self._thread = None
            self._cancelled.clear()
```

When using it, pass in a delay in seconds as a floating point number, and the callback:

```
from tkinter import Button

def callback():
    print("Hello, world!")

b = Button(
    master,
    text="Click me!",
    command=DelayedCancellable(2.0, callback)
)
```

The above button will cause `Hello, world!` to be printed, unless you click the button again within 2 seconds.

The extra `invoked` and `cancelled` actions could be used to update the UI so there is a bit more feedback for the user:

```
from tkinter import Button, RAISED, SUNKEN

def button_invoked():
    b.config(relief=SUNKEN)

def button_cancelled():
    b.config(relief=RAISED)

def callback():
    button_cancelled()  # clear state
    print("Hello, world!")

b = Button(
    master,
    text="Click me!",
    command=DelayedCancellable(2.0, callback, button_invoked, button_cancelled)
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this using a `threading.Timer` instead of a `threading.Thread`? That already has a wait, and a cancel function built-in.

Comment: @Heike: I always forget about `Timer()`. It's [implementation is essentially the same](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e3c25fc902eedcd5c593fac58f35645961f55bf4/Lib/threading.py#L1153-L1178), but adding the `_on_cancelled` callback would require replacing the whole `run()` method anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach from Martijn Pieters. I've used .after to schedule an event to happen after 2 seconds rather than a seperate thread.

Clicking the button once will cause the `ConfirmedAction` function to be called after 2 seconds. Clicking the button a second time, within the 2 second window, will cancel the timer.

```
import tkinter as tk

def ConfirmedAction():
    print("Doing something")

class ConfirmButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self,master,**kw):
        self.confirmcommand = kw.pop('confirm',None)
        super(ConfirmButton, self).__init__(master, **kw)
        self.timer = None
        self['command'] = self._clicked
    def _clicked(self):
        if not self.timer:
            self.timer = self.after(2000,self._doAction)
        else:
            self.after_cancel(self.timer)
            self.timer = None
            print("Action Cancelled")
    def _doAction(self):
        self.confirmcommand()
        self.timer = None

root = tk.Tk()
btn1 = ConfirmButton(root,text="Hello",confirm=ConfirmedAction)
btn1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You two did very well, although yours is good, Martin's code is simpler, thus requires less time to start.